# How to handle Akka HTTP client response failure

Tags: akka-http

Akka HTTP client requests return Future[HttpResponse] - how should one handle the Future failing? Just log an error or re-throw it to the supervisor?

Is there documentation of the type of errors that can be returned by thrown by the client (and hence automatically propagated to the supervisor  ) as well as errors that can cause the Furure to fail.

Answer (score 2):

It's matter of taste mostly. I typically convert `Future[HttpResponse]` to `Future[Try[HttpResponse]]` and then handle it as

```
response.flatMap { tryResp =>

  tryResp match {
    case Success(res) =>
      res.status match {
        case OK =>
          // Unmarshal response here into Future[Something]
        case Found =>
          // Handle  redirect by calling requestBlhBlah() again with anotehr URI
        case _ =>
          // I got status code I didn't expect so I wrap it along with body into Future failure
          Unmarshal(res.entity).to[String].flatMap { body =>
            Future.failed(new IOException(s"The response status is ${res.status} [${request.uri}] and response body is $body"))
          }
      }
    case Failure(ex) =>
      Future.failed(ex)
  }
}
```

If you're using flow-based client you can also specify `Decider` to handle errors

```
val decider: Decider = {
  case ex =>
    ex.printStackTrace()
    Supervision.Stop // Passes error down to subscriber
}
```

and then use it in either materializer

```
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(system).withSupervisionStrategy(decider))(system)
```

or in per-flow basis via `.withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))`

As per `Future` failure it's up to you how to handle it. You can convert failure to something else using `recoverWith` or log it in `Future.onFailure`.

Comment: Ahm... I kinda do the same thing but with Either instead of Try - the end result is that if everything is ok, Future[Something] is returned, otherwise, a failed future is returned with either the exception in the original response (Future[HttpResponse]), or some customer exception we define for known error response from the target service

Comment: However (1) The exception returned by the future is never propagated to the supervisor, and hence never handled, (2) We should know what exceptions  the client can return, and either handle or log them

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still hard to decide how to handle errors if we don't know what they could be. Errors thrown by the client are handled by the supervisor, but without knowing what error can be returned in the Future, it's impossible to know how/if we should handle them.

Comment: Well, I just cover for cases I know about and others go to log :)